# Action of tensor product of operators on entangled state

Tags: quantum-entanglement, open-quantum-systems

Let $S$ be a system described by the density operator $\rho_S$. Consider the operator

$$\mathcal{L_t}\left[ \rho_S \right] = \gamma (t) \left[ \sigma_z \rho_S \sigma_z - \rho_S\right] $$

where $\sigma_z$ is the $z$ Pauli matrix and $\gamma(t)$ a time dependent coefficient.

Now consider an additional system A. The overall system $S + A$ is in a maximally entangled state

$$\rho_{SA} = |\Psi \rangle \langle \Psi |.$$

In this case, the density matrix of $S$ is obtained by tracing out the ancillary system $A$
$$\rho_S = Tr_A \left[ \rho_{SA} \right]$$

How to explicit the action of the operator

$$\mathcal{L}_t \otimes Id_A $$

where $Id_A$ is the identity of tha ancillary system $A$, on the maximally entangled state $\rho_{SA}$?

In particular, prove that if $\gamma (t) < 0$ then

$$lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \frac {|| \left[ Id_{SA} + \left[ \mathcal{L}_t \otimes Id_A \right]\epsilon  \right] |\Psi \rangle \langle \Psi |||_1 -1}{\epsilon} = -2 \gamma (t)$$

where $|| X ||_1 = Tr\left[\sqrt{ X X^{\dagger} } \right]$ is the trace norm.